# Can you retighten timing chain cover without redoing RTV?

Tags: escape, gasket

I'm working on the timing chain cover for my 2002 Ford Escape..

[image]

Here is the bolt pattern (each goes to 18 ft lbs).

[image]

I will refer to each bolt by its position in the bolt pattern. I need to take off bolts **14, 10, 4, 3, 11, and 15**. Then one at a time I need to move a bolt from *9, 7, 6, 5, 8, or 12* into one of the bolt holes from the previous step. This is because the bolts currently in positions *9, 7, 6, 5, 8, and 12* have studs on them that that need to be in positions **14, 10, 4, 3, 11, and 15**. Basically, I put these bolts in the wrong holes and now I got to move them around. At the least secure part of the job only 9/16 of the bolts will be in place.

So am I wondering can I just move all these bolts around, loosen everything up, and then redo the tightening sequence or do I need to take the timing chain cover off, clean everything up, and then reinstall with new RTV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are not breaking the two pieces apart (completely removing the cover), you should have no issue doing what you want to do. I'm assuming the RTV which is there is fully cured? If so, you could take all the bolts out of it and then put them back in and should not have an issue with it. The only time you'd need to redo the RTV is if you've actually broken the seal itself. Removing the bolts isn't going to do that.